# Select all of the columns in a row except for one in RadGrid using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have set my radgrid to multiple column selection so I can select columns individually(without executing a postback). What I want is when I click one column in a certain row. All other columns(except the last will be selected) and I will fire a function right after. Is it possible? all I see around the net are getting the values of each column. All I need is to select all so it look like a row select(except one column/cell) isn't selected and I can easy get the datakeyvalue so I won't need any help on that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

$(function() {

```
$("td").click(function() {
    var lastElem = $(this).parent().children(":last-child");
    $(this).parent().children().not(lastElem).css("background-color","red");
});
```

});

Include Jquery in your code and include this as Javascript.

Let me know for any issues

Comment: I'm using telerik radgrid view, and I want to select it not change it's background